# How to generate random URL in urls.py each time the user logs in (Django)?

Tags: python, django, sesame

I am trying to create a random URL that can be accessed only once after the user logs in.

I am using `django-sesame` to generate different URLs each time the user logs in. To do this, I have set the `SESAME_ONE_TIME` setting to `True` in `settings.py`, and I am able to redirect the user to the random URL like this:

`views.py`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import my_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
import sesame

@login_required()
def password_form(request):  

    url_extension = sesame.utils.get_query_string(request.user)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            update_session_auth_hash(request, user)  
            return redirect('/success/' + url_extension)
    else:
        form = PasswordChangeForm(request.user)

    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, "form.html", context)
```

However, in `urls.py` I don't know how to add the URL to `urlpatterns` properly. This probably sounds weird, but, for a lack of better wording, is there any way you can add a parameter that can accept a randomly generated value in `path`, like:

`urls.py`:

```
from app.views import password_form

urlpatterns = [path('success/' + random_variable, password_form),]
```

If not, is there any way I can make the `url_extension` variable global, so that I can use it in `urls.py`, by bypassing the need for `request` (e.g. setting `url_extension` as an attribute to a function in `views.py` and using it as `function.url_extension` in `urls.py`)?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a regular expression where you allow success at the starting and the anything after that. Your regular expression in url will be something like this - success/.*$. This check for a success and then allows *(everything) after /.